# How do I fix this solidity compiler error on my onlyOwner modifier?

Tags: solidity

Here is the modifier I'm having trouble with. It looks right to me, but I'm still getting an error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }
```

I am getting this error message when I compile with Truffle:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol

ParserError: Invalid token.
  --> project:/contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol:48:1:
   |
48 |         require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function.");
   |                                                                                 ^
```

I used Truffle Compile with a standard onlyOwner modifier and got a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your question with more information about your contract?

It seems like your trying to use the `onlyOwner` modifier from the `Ownable` contract and you might be using it wrong

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Test is Ownable {

    function heresHowYouUseIt() public onlyOwner {
    //logic
    }
}
```